# Cannot resolve import module in core library file android

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, dependencies, android-support-library

when i debug my app, i found some module in lib core android (such as Activity.java,ActivityThread.java, Handler.java, Looper.java) cannot resolved. I had update sdk, but it still error. Please guide me how to fix it. Thanks very much.

**Some module in lib file android cannot resolve**

[image]

**My sdk update**

[image]

**My build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.huyma.testmap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: Please do not include images of code - include the actual code.  Moreover, if you do include an image, actually include the image!  Not just a link to the image.